# Java: find current working JAR

Tags: java, file, jar, working-directory

I know that the system property "user.dir" returns the current working directory; the directory containing that file that is currently running.

I am wondering, how would I be able to go one step farther? I need to find the current working *file*. I am writing a little app that is kind of like an auto-updater, and I need to know the file that needs to be updated. For example, if I run a file from **C:/test.jar** I want to actually know, in code, that the current location of the file that is running is **C:/test.jar** so that I can write (new) data to it.

I've tried an approach like this:

```
    ClassLoader loader = Test.class.getClassLoader();
    System.out.println(loader.getResource("Test.class"));
```

However, it prints out:

```
3/5/12 7:50:16.914 PM [0x0-0x31031].com.apple.JarLauncher: rsrc:Test.class
```

(I am running this on a Mac - I got that line from the Console).
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file

Comment: Accepted answer still returns the directory.

Comment: `path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);` will take care of that.

Comment: Diego was correct, the *non* accepted answer from Fab is working (at least working on Ubuntu I just tested it): http://stackoverflow.com/a/6849255/1012381

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With credits to [Fab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/866064/fab) in the following post:
[Jar path+name from currently running jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849255/1012381)

```
String path = Test.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Ah, test is the current class.

Answer (score 0):

This will print the current file's path.

```
File f = new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
        System.out.println(f.getPath());
```